# Monad Implementation in Typescript

Tags: functional-programming, typescript, monads

Having been introduced to monads through Scala, I am trying to add the generalized design pattern to my toolkit by implementing it in a language I use more regularly (typescript).

My tests pass (bottom snippet), but I worry that I am committing heresies and/or doing it wrong.  Could anyone suggest improvements?

I'll post code here, but the source is accessible and easily runnable/testable on branch `stackExchangeCodeReview` of [this repo](https://github.com/Manningham/ts-playground) (requires node).

I have a base class, `Monad<T>`...

```
export type mapping<T, U> = (x: T, ...args: any[]) => U;

/**
 * Describes the base monadic operations and holds state in two properties:
 *
 *   `_wrapped` is the monadic container, managed in sub-classes
 *
 *   `_unwrapped` is the original value passed to the constructor (unit).  This is included for convenience, since
 *       the `_wrapped` value is not guaranteed to preserve the monad's input, and it could be difficult to
 *       functionally map back to that input.
 */

export abstract class Monad<T> {

  public abstract wrapped: any;
  public abstract unit: <T>(x: T, ...args: any[]) => Monad<T>;
  public abstract flatMap: <U>(f: mapping<T, Monad<U>>) => Monad<U>;

  private _unwrapped: T;
  public get unwrapped(): T {
    return this._unwrapped;
  }

  constructor (x: T, ...args: any[]) {
    this._unwrapped = x;
  }

}
```

... which is used to create a sub-class `Logger<T>`, which performs operations and keeps a log of those operations.  (inspired by [this JS implementation of Haskell's writer monad](http://blog.klipse.tech/javascript/2016/08/31/monads-javascript.html))

```
import {Monad, mapping} from './monad';

/**
 * Keeps a log of operations and their return values by accepting labels for lifted operations.
 */

interface ILog <T> {
  value: T;
  log: string;
}

export class Logger<T> extends Monad<T> {

  private _wrapped: ILog<T>;
  public get wrapped(): ILog<T> {
    return this._wrapped;
  }

  public static lift = <T, U>(f: mapping<T, U>, label: string) => (x: T, log: string) => new Logger(f(x), log + '\n' + label);

  constructor (x: T, log: string = 'unit') {
    super(x);
    this._wrapped = { value: x, log: `${log} -> ${x}` };
  }

  public unit = (x: T, log: string) => new Logger(x, log);

  public flatMap = <U>(f: mapping<T, Logger<U>>) => f(this.unwrapped, this.wrapped.log);

}
```

It can be used like this...

```
import {Logger} from './monads/logger';

const double = (n: number) => n * 2;
const square = (n: number) => n * n;
const gtTen = (n: number) => n > 10;

const lDouble = Logger.lift(double, 'double');
const lSquare = Logger.lift(square, 'square');
const lGtTen = Logger.lift(gtTen, 'greater than ten');

const chain = new Logger(2).flatMap(lDouble).flatMap(lSquare).flatMap(lGtTen);

console.log(chain.wrapped.log, '\n\nwrapped.value: ', chain.wrapped.value, '\n\nunwrapped: ', chain.unwrapped);
// unit -> 2
// double -> 4
// square -> 16
// greater than ten -> true 
// 
// wrapped.value:  true 
// 
// unwrapped:  true
```

... and I am testing that it fulfills the monadic contract in these passing tests:

```
import {mapping} from './monad';
import {Logger} from './logger';

describe('logger', () => {

  it('should initialize', () => {
    expect(Logger).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should fulfill left unit law: `unit(x).flatMap(f) == f(x)`', () => {
    const x = 1;
    const f: mapping<number, Logger<number>> = (n: number) => new Logger(n);
    const leftSide = new Logger(x).flatMap(f);
    const rightSide = f(x);

    const expected = jasmine.objectContaining({
      unwrapped: rightSide.unwrapped,
      wrapped: rightSide.wrapped
    });

    expect(leftSide).toEqual(expected);
  });

  it('should fulfill right unit law: `unit(x).flatMap(unit) == unit(x)`', () => {
    const x = 1;
    const leftSide = new Logger(x);
    const rightSide = leftSide.flatMap(leftSide.unit);

    const expected = jasmine.objectContaining({
      unwrapped: rightSide.unwrapped,
      // Logs in `wrapped` will not match since left and right side go through different operations
      // wrapped: rightSide.wrapped
    });

    expect(leftSide).toEqual(expected);
  });

  it('should fulfill law of associativity: `unit(x).flatMap(f).flatMap(g) == unit(x).flatMap(x => f(x).flatMap(g))`', () => {
    const x = 1;
    const f: mapping<number, Logger<number>> = (n: number) => new Logger(n, 'f');
    const g: mapping<number, Logger<number>> = (n: number) => new Logger(n + 2, 'g');
    const m = new Logger(x);
    const leftSide = m.flatMap(f).flatMap(g);
    const rightSide = m.flatMap(num => f(num).flatMap(g));

    const expected = jasmine.objectContaining({
      unwrapped: rightSide.unwrapped,
      wrapped: rightSide.wrapped
    });

    expect(leftSide).toEqual(expected);
  });

  it('should keep a log of all operations and return values', () => {
    const double = (n: number) => n * 2;
    const square = (n: number) => n * n;
    const gtTen = (n: number) => n > 10;

    const lDouble = Logger.lift(double, 'double');
    const lSquare = Logger.lift(square, 'square');
    const lGtTen = Logger.lift(gtTen, 'greater than ten');

    const chain = new Logger(2).flatMap(lDouble).flatMap(lSquare).flatMap(lGtTen);
    expect(chain.wrapped.value).toBe(true);
    expect(chain.wrapped.log).toBe('unit -> 2\ndouble -> 4\nsquare -> 16\ngreater than ten -> true');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export type mapping<T, U> = (x: T, ...args: any[]) => U;

export abstract class Monad<T> {
  public abstract unit: (x: T, ...args: any[]) => Monad<T>;
  public abstract flatMap: <U>(f: mapping<T, Monad<U>>) => Monad<U>;
}
```

I've dropped everything that did not match the monad typeclass members in Haskell.

- There is no need to store `wrapped` since this is already represented by `this`.
- I've removed `unwrapped`. It conveys the idea that a monad always wraps a value from an underlying type. However, this artificially restricts the idea.

---

```
export class Logger<T> extends Monad<T> {

  private _log: string[];
  public get log(): string[] { return this._log; }
  private _value: T;
  public get value(): T { return this._value; }

  public static liftLogger = <T2, U>(f: mapping<T2, U>, label: string) => ((x: T2) => new Logger(f(x), [label]));

  constructor (x: T, log: string[] = []) {
    super();
    this._value= x;
    this._log= log;
  }

  public unit = (x: T, log: string): Logger<T> => new Logger(x, [log]);

  public flatMap = <U>(f: mapping<T, Logger<U>>) => {
    let x = f(this.unwrapped);
    return new Logger(x.unwrapped, [...this.wrapped, ...x.wrapped]);
  }
}
```

- I've removed the `ILog<T>` interface. It stored another `value` that was already stored.
- To match implementations with the [Writer monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer), I've changed the log entry type from `string` to `string[]`.
- `lift` did not only lifted the function, it implemented the monadic bind for the `Logger<T>` type. This is now done inside `flatMap`.

---

- I've not looked at the `MList` type.
- I'd like to see an implementation that did not rely on `Monad<T>` being a base class. In Haskell, a type is made a monad by creating a `Monad` typeclass instance for it.

---

Edit 1: Rename `_wrapped` -> `_log`, `_unwrapped` -> `value`

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I've skimmed and will have a closer look Sat.

Comment: These are some nice improvements and I've implemented and simplified the syntax a bit on [this branch](https://github.com/Manningham/ts-playground/tree/secr).

I made `Monad` an interface instead of a base class, which I suppose is as close to a Haskell typeclass as we can get in Typescript.

I re-implemented some logic to add the values to the operations log, since it seemed like a shame to have lost that in your revision.  Thanks for your feedback!